# Замена символов в string. "i" буква должна стать "i+1"

Tags: c++, строки

Могу сделать либо так,чтобы заменялась лишь одна буква,либо все буквы после выбранной.К примеру в строке qwerty выбрать r и будет qwerry(то что мне и нужно),но если слово длинное,то заменяет либо одну первую букву,либо вообще не заменяет.

```
string str;
   cin >> str;
    char b;
    cin >> b; 
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {

        if (str[i] == b)
          {
                str[i + 1] = b;
                break;
          }

    }
```

Comment: Что значит: _если слово длинное,то заменяет либо одну первую букву,либо вообще не заменяет._?  Насколько длинное должно быть слово?  Как определить, будет замена или нет?  В представленном коде может быть ошибка выхода за пределы строки, например при замене `y` в `qwerty` -- какой должен быть результат кстати?

Comment: @NowhereMan, у строки ещё нолик в конце, так что там выхода за границу нет, но затирание этого нуля может привести к последующему выходу при выводе, например.

Comment: Поясните, что значит `"i" буква должна стать "i+1"` на примере.

Answer (score 0):

Меняет только одну букву потому, что у вас после замены символа стоит прерывание цикла - оператор `break;`. И как правильно написали в комментариях - в общем случае вы затираете ноль, завершающий строку.
Должно быть так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length()-1; i++) // цикл до str.length()-1
    if (str[i] == b)
    {
        str[i + 1] = b;
        break;     // убрать, чтобы перезаписывалось больше 1 символа
    }
```